# Disable long press on WKWebView does not work

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, ios15

I am trying to disable long press on my WKWebView as it allows to drag and drop of urls which is unwanted on my side. Just to clarify I don't want to disable the WKActionSheet but just the drag & drop feature of the links.

I tried:

```
webView.allowsLinkPreview = false
```

and

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.style.webkitTouchCallout='none';")
```

but these does not seem to have any effect. Anybody have an idea? My app has minimum target iOS 15.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the selection on long press by setting a property on WKPreferences to false. Configure the WKWebView like you see below

```
func configureWebView() {
    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webConfiguration.preferences.isTextInteractionEnabled = false
    webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    webView.uiDelegate = self
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but unfortunately doesn't work. This one disables the interaction with all the text so the user can't copy and paste the text etc. which I want to keep enabled. And long press/dragging on the links is still enabled.